# Не получается сделать правильный API запрос

Tags: python, post, api, get, requests

Добрый день, возможно кто-то из Вас работал с сервисом(worksection.com), если же нет, все равно хочу попросить помощи, потому что не могу понять что делаю не так.

И так, краткое вступление

1. Обращение к API через http GET или POST запрос по адресу http://your-domain.com/api/admin/, где your-domain.com - адрес аккаунта в системе Worksection.

В запросе обязательно должны присутствовать параметры:

action – операция

page – url проекта, задачи или подзадачи в системе без адреса аккаунта. Например: /project/12345/

hash – проверочная запись, формируется как MD5 от трех склеенных параметров page, action и вашего ключа apikey.

Apikey может получить владелец аккаунта на странице http://your-domain.com/account/api/

Пример формирования проверочной записи для языка php: 
`$hash = md5($page.$action.$apikey).`

Текстовые данные должны передаваться в кодировке UTF-8

2. Ответ формируется в формате JSON, кодировка UTF-8

Далее я пытаюсь воплотить это в код -

```
import json
import requests
import hashlib

adr = 'http://milkiweed.worksection.com/api/admin/'
action = 'get_priority'
page = 'project/205032/6086356/'
apikey = 'e6***b080e162****88b5656***6d0'

items = page + action + apikey

hash = hashlib.md5(items.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
r = requests.post(adr,json=hash)
data = json.loads(r.text)
print(data)
```

При запуске получаю ошибку - `{'status': 'error', 'status_code': 0, 'message': 'Action is required'}`

Исходя из документации эта ошибка свидетельствует о том, что запрос либо проверочная запись сформированы неверно

Подскажите пожалуйста, скорее всего я обращаюсь не так, как нужно.

Comment: сравните http запросы, которые php и python генерируют. `json=hash` выглядит подозрительно.

Comment: @jfs `http://your-domain.com/api/admin/?action=get_priority&hash=HASH` 

Вот пример запроса на php

Comment: какой http метод GET или POST? Какой Content-Type x-www-form-urlencoded?

Comment: @jfs get метод, насчет второго не особо понял)

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы выполнить http GET-запрос и получить данные в json формате:

```
import hashlib
import requests

h = hashlib.md5((page + action + apikey).encode()).hexdigest()
data = requests.get('http://your-domain.com/api/admin/' + page
                    + '?action=' + action + '&hash=' + h).json()
```

Comment: К сожалению вот такое. `{'status': 'error', 'status_code': 2, 'message': 'Action hash is missed or invalid'}`

Comment: @MilkiweedGtlt: не зная как действительный запрос должен выглядеть сложно что-то дальше сказать. Код на Питоне выполняет точно что вы попросили. Обновите вопрос и явно приведите, что php код посылает и сравните с python кодом (можно запустить сервер локально: `nc -l -p 8888` и заменить `your-domain.com` на `localhost:8888`, чтобы запрос увидеть или просто Wireshark запустите)

Answer (score 0):

```
r = requests.post(adr+'?action='+action+'&hash='+hash)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Возможно, ответ верный, только вот совершенно непонятный в таком виде

Comment: В документации имеется пример запроса: https://your-domain.com/api/admin/?action=get_projects&hash=HASH. Строку r = requests.post(adr,json=hash) следует заменить на r = requests.post(adr+'?action='+action+'&hash='+hash). Для различных запросов она будет выглядеть по разному